# Applications of the pigeonhole principle (strong form)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle, combinatorial-proofs

If $n \ge 25$ and $n = 8r_1 + 5r_2$ (with $r_1, r_2$ being natural numbers), prove that  either $r_1 \ge 2$ or $r_2 \ge 2$. So is uttered the question which I found in a book on  introductory combinatorics. I believe it involves using the pigeonhole principle, and so the way I attempted at it is:

If we distribute $2(2 - 1) + 1 = 3$ units into $r_1, r_2$, then either $r_1$ has at least 2 ($\ge 2$) or $r_2$ has at least 2 units ($\ge 2$). So if we show that $r_1 + r_2 \ge 3$ then the conclusion can be reached. I believe this is supposed to be shown through the fact that $8r_1 + 5r_2 \ge 26$ but I don't know how. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are over complicating things, suppose neither were greater than or equal to $2$ then what happens?

Comment: I've considered your reasoning, but the book specifically asks to *use* the principle; hence I would like to try involving it.

Comment: If you have to distribute $26$ items (or more) at two places, one counting times $8$, the other one counting times $5$, by the pigeonhole principle you have at least $2$ items in one place. This is all, and you have used your "principle". So either $r_1$ or $r_2$ is $\ge 2$.

Comment: The closest that I can come is to reason that $8r_1 + 5r_2 < 8(r_1 + r_2).$  Therefore, if $(r_1 + r_2) \leq 2,$ then $$8r_1 + 5r_2  < 8(r_1 + r_2) \leq 16.$$

Comment: I believe I have successfully implemented the principle: if $16 + 10 - 2 + 1 = 25$ (I have mistakenly written $26$ in the post) units are distributed into the values $8r_1$ and $5r_2$. Then, by the principle, either $8r_1 \ge 2$ or $5r_2 \ge 2$; hence either $r_1 \ge 2$ or $r_2 \ge 2$. Is this reasoning correct? You must excuse me, for I just started reading about the pigeonhole principle and would like obvious applications of it to better myself.

Comment: Does my last comment resolve the problem?

Comment: well, in my inexpert opinion, I believe the task was to show that either $r_1 \ge 2$ or $r_2 \ge 2$; however what you have shown is that $8r_1 + 5r_2 \le 16$. I do not see why you attempted to do this. Though, is the reasoning provided in my last comment correct?

Answer (score 1):

A scale is loaded up with several starfish and octopuses. Each starfish weighs five ounces, each octopus weighs eight ounces. The total weight of the scale is $n$.

Each ounce is a pigeon, and there are two holes. The ounce goes in the "starfish" hole if it came from a starfish, and the "octopus" hole otherwise. Since there are at least $25$ pigeons, and two holes, by the generalized pigeonhole principle, there must exist a hole with at least $\lceil 25/2\rceil=13$ pigeons. That is, there are either $13$ ounces of starfish, or $13$ ounces of octopus. In the first case, there must be at least $\lceil 13/5\rceil =3$ starfish. In the second case, there must be $\lceil 13/8\rceil=2$ octopuses. Either way, some creature appears at least twice, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you much for the requested proof and demonstration! Is, though, the proof that I gave in the comments above valid aswell? You see, I only just started investigating the idea and even if the proofs are fairly obvious I still seek affirmation from the more professional. Thank you, again.

Comment: It is correct, after you fix these two typos: "Either $8r_1\ge \color{blue}{16}$ or $5r_2\ge \color{red}{10}$. Hence, either $r_1\ge 2$ or $r_2\ge 2$."

Comment: Ahh, right. That was what was intended to be written. Thank you for the affirmation.